# Proving that a subsequence of a function converges to the same limit.

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck with trying to prove the following:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=l$

Prove that
$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=l$ for every sequence $(x_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n = a$

I'm really not sure how to go about doing that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I [don't believe](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) that you have no idea. Please read that link and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I had another go at it after a bit of a break, and with Fred's response as well I think I get it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=l$ means:

$(*)$ for every $\epsilon >0$ there is $ \delta >0$ such that $|x-a|< \delta$ implies $|f(x)-l|< \epsilon$.

Now let $(x_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence with $x_n \to a$. We have to show that $f(x_n) \to l$.

To this end let $ \epsilon >0$. Now choose $\delta$ as in $(*)$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n-a|< \delta$ for all $n>N$.

Hence $|f(x_n)-l|< \epsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: I am new to MS.  Why did someone downvote Fred's answer?

Comment: Why the downvote ?????????

Comment: You are not new, and you are astonished.

Comment: @Fred I don't know exactly why you were downvoted, but I think it's because the downvote arrow says "This answer is not useful". Some people (myself included) believe that we on math.SE should help people help themselves, not serve them complete solutions, because that doesn't really help them in the long run. I don't believe it hard enough to downvote answers which are technically correct, but I still don't like it when it happens. It teaches people that it's OK to ask what we consider bad questions. That being said, voting on this site seems, at times, completely arbitrary.

Comment: @Arthur Sometimes, showing people how easy an answer to their frivolous questions can be has more salutary effect.

Comment: @user539887 And I personally believe in helping people discover on their own, not giving the to solution them directly. Teach a man to fish and all that. Now, if you go through all my posts here, you will probably find me a bit hypocritical. Some times I find it difficult to hold back. That's one reason why I don't downvote when others give full solutions.