# Putnam and Beyond problem 321

Tags: calculus, contest-math

If $\lim_{x\to0^+} x^x=1$ then is $\lim_{x\to0^+} x^{x+1}=0$? 
Similarly can we conclude $\lim_{n\to\infty} (k/n^2)^{k/n^2 +1}=0$? If not, why?
Edit: 
Why is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (k/n^2)^{k/n^2 +1}=1/2$ but not 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that for any $x_n\to x_0$

$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=L \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n)=L$$

Refer to [Proving that a subsequence of a function converges to the same limit.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2704471/505767)

Note that also $\frac 1n \to 0$ but $\sum \frac 1n=\infty$.

Indeed if the limit of $a_n \to 0$ with $a_i > 0$ then $\sum a_n$ can't be equal to zero.

Comment: Ok but $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (k/n^2)^{k/n^2 +1}=1/2$, why is it not $0$

Comment: @RTS Why are you considering the series? The OP is about the sequence.

Comment: I thought I made a mistake with the limits in the question. The original question I was trying to solve is about the series

Comment: If the limit of $a_n \to 0$ with $a_i > 0$ then $\sum a_n$ can't be equal to zero.

Comment: Why can't you use the limit laws to separate a sum into its individual components?    I know a counterexample, but is there a specific reason why? Edit: I just realized my mistake in all of this.

Comment: Your last two sentences don't make sense as written.

Comment: @RTS The question is simple for any $n$ we have $(k/n^2)^{k/n^2 +1}>0$ then for $k\neq 0$ $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (k/n^2)^{k/n^2 +1}>\sum_{n=1}^1 (k/n^2)^{k/n^2 +1}=k^{k+1}>0$$